# Reverse for 'code_front' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category_slug': u'code'}' not found

Tags: django

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Reverse for 'code_front' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'category_slug': u'code'}' not found.
```

I am new at this, please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error you're getting is because there's no match in your urls.py for the view and parameters you're using.

An example:

If your urls.py look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^YOUR_PATTERN/(?P<PARAMETER>.*)', your_view, name='code_front'),
)
```

You can reverse it's url like this:

**In a template:**

- Using a value directly:

  `{% url code_front 'some_value' %}`
- You can use variables as parameter values:

  `{% url code_front variable %}`
- Using multiple parameters (if you're view needs them):

  `{% url code_front variable, another_variable %}`
- Or using named parameters:

  `{% url code_front parameter=variable %}`

**The same can be done in your python code:**

- `reverse('code\_front', args=['some_value'])`
- `reverse('code\_front', args=[variable])`
- `reverse('code\_front', args=[variable, another_variable])`
- `reverse('code\_front', kwargs={'parameter': variable})`

You'll need to import the `reverse` function:

`from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`

Answer (score 1):

Some basics:

1. Make sure you're passing the right arguments for the view function that the url resolves to.
2. Make sure your that the reverse function only gets a single match, if not, give your url a unique name to reverse it with.
3. If you're using `get_absolute_url`/`permalink` then make sure you've passed the right parameters.
4. Make sure `code_front` exists as a valid item for a reverse lookup.